# What is a good Java lib for image transformations and backbuffer rendering without need of front buffer for server side programming?

Tags: java, image

I'm trying to find a simple library to fit my needs, but because I am really unaware of Java libs (I use to do everything from scratch in any programming language that I work with) and the exactly thing that I need is complicated for a Google search query, it would be greatly appreciated any recomendation.

What I am trying to achieve is to do some image manipulation in server side using the sumitted info from a web browser. Is not simple scale or crop, but to be able to rotate, scale and crop every single sprite and draw it in the exactly order to compose the final hight resolution image in a backbuffer then save it in bmp and make some copies in lower resolution as png.

I have no problem with the interface from client side to the server, also I have experience in game programming, so I know how to work with double buffering. What I need is a library that let me do all these images transformation and backbuffer drawing without the need of a front buffer and graphics hardware, because the output will not be the screen, and to be able to access every pixel argb from memory, able to save in various image formats and as a plus but not requiered able to render text from different font.

Thanks for any reply and any recomendations to improve my question will be apreciated too (I am new around here).

Answer (score 1):

A couple of libraries you may find helpful for server side image processing in Java:

- JH Labs image filters : http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/index.html
- imgscalr image scaling library: https://github.com/thebuzzmedia/imgscalr

Also don't forget the good old BufferedImage API that is already in Java: it has quick a decent range of functionality for basic image manipulation (cropping etc.)

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html

Comment: +1 to trying to do this with `BufferedImage`. It's always nice to be able to solve a problem without dragging in yet another library.